# Could you help me translate this sentence?

Tags: translation

I've been reading this article which I can understand fine in general, but it's the last couple of sentences in which the translator gives his own opinion I'm at a loss. The article is about how Lego has been split into specific sets aimed at different genders.

http://www.gizmodo.jp/2014/02/1981.html

> ただ、訳者の超私見ですが、子供の遊ぶ力って、大人のメッセージ伝達力なんか軽々と圧倒してくれて、本人が興味を持てば「自分はこの商品のターゲットか」とか関係なく遊びたがるんじゃないでしょうか。

Except for the first part where the translator states he's going to give us his opinion it just won't come together in my mind.

I think the translator says it doesn't really matter what the person with the critique says(she picked out the lego example herself) because the children will play with the things they want to play with.

It's probably wrong, but the best I can do right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i understand it :

> ただ、訳者の超私見ですが

This is merely the translator's personal opinion but,

> 子供の遊ぶ力って、大人のメッセージ伝達力なんか軽々と圧倒してくれて

children's "playing power/force" easily overwhelms something like adult's message transmission power, so

> 本人が興味を持てば「自分はこの商品のターゲットか」とか関係なく遊びたがるんじゃないでしょうか

if the person himself is interested, regardless of something like "being the target of this merchandise" wouldn't he want to play?

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for providing their thougts. It's Ryan's more literal bit by bit translation which really enabled me to understand this construction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's what she's saying and the translator's Japanese is little wordy.
You're translation is OK.

You also need to translate the part where she mentions about 「自分はこの商品のターゲットか」and all other things that goes with it.

I think Ryan did very good job.

My english skill isn't good enough to come up with a definitive translation as Ryan did.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure it was Ok for me to just translate it thou, maybe I'll edit with some clarifications if i know what part they were grammatically having trouble with

Comment: I think whoever wrote that Japanese is writing somewhat colloquially and it is not a very good one. But I think you did very good job. I bet your Japanese is better than us native speakers.

Comment: believe me it's not even close I'm still at the start of my journey :) but thanks a lot that's a huge boost to my confidence coming from a native speaker

Answer (score 3):

This is my attempt. I have taken some literary license so any comments are welcome.

> ただ、訳者の超私見ですが、子供の遊ぶ力って、大人のメッセージ伝達力なんか軽々と圧倒してくれて、本人が興味を持てば「自分はこの商品のターゲットか」とか関係なく遊びたがるんじゃないでしょうか。
>
> This very much just my opinion as a translator but when it comes to a child's capacity to play with a toy, you can rely on it to overcome any built-in message from adults. If the child is interested in a product, won't they want to enjoy experimenting with it, regardless of whether they were its intended consumer?

Notes:

- I have translated くれる as 'you can rely on'
- Not quite sure about the use of 超: considered over-interpreting?(-> clumsy) but settled on "very much" on advice from virmaior
- I originally took  遊ぶ to have wider meaning of fool around in the sense of "enjoy experimenting with it". Possibly this is better expression?
- Could not decide whether the writer was specifically referring to Lego or any toy. Both seem to work but I decided the generic sense was better in context of paragraph.

Comment: I think 超私見 means "this is very much just my personal opinion"

Comment: I think that's a very good translation and what one should actually use if translating the original text for a specific purpose, still i feel it's far better written than the the original text which is more casual and using relatively unusual/casual expressions such as 遊ぶ力, とか, and 超, than again it maybe only appear that way to me as a none native speaker

Comment: @Ryan: you may be right. I've modified the last line into a question but it could probably be improved further.